# Tab key in Microsoft Word does not increase indent in bullet lists

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I create a bullet list, of any type and after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of increasing the indent it just injected white-space.

I'm using the default template (.dot), there's been no changes to it, can't see any misconfigured settings for this either...

[image: Tabbing Issue Screen Shot]

Note: this is happening in Word 2007.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One possibility is AutoCorrect settings were changed.

To fix this, click the Microsoft Office button, select `Word Options`. Under `Proofing`, click `AutoCorrect Options...`. Under `AutoFormat As You Type` tab (in the `Automatically as you type` section), make sure that the "Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces" option is checked.

[image]

Comment: The "left and first indent" setting is the one causing the OP's problem specifically, so +1 for that.
The other settings do "smart" things like changing text to a bullet list if you start with a tab and a dash for example. They don't impact or cause the problem as described.

Comment: YES! Well done, nice find. Thanks that did it. I've uploaded an image if you'd like to edit your answer, otherwise I'll link here anyway: http://nickjosevski.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/word2007bulletsetting.jpg

Comment: I am having the same problem in Powerpoint 2010, but the AutoCorrect options are different: http://superuser.com/questions/367843/tab-key-does-not-indent-in-powerpoint-2010 and I can't use `ctrl + M`, because they are already in use for `new slide`.

Comment: For Word 2011 on the Mac, this option is found in `Tools` > `Autocorrect...` > `Autoformat as You Type` > `Tabs and backspace set left indent`.

Comment: In my case, the option is already enabled but still TAB does increase indent Level. Someone, please help

Answer (score 16):

On Windows, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>; on MacOS, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Doesn't work for Word 2011 for Mac.

Comment: On Windows, this is the best option. Unlike `ctrl`+`shift`+`M`, the bullets are properly formatted.

Comment: @james-garriss Mac doesn't have Alt key... But `Control+Shift+M` should work http://superuser.com/a/460183/259273 (other posts suggest `Shift+Control+Arrow keys`)

Comment: The correct solution on Mac is Shift+Control+Arrow keys. Control-Shift-M only inserts tabs.

Comment: Why the heck does this work and everything else doesn't?? (I wish someone could [edit] this answer to add more info, but it's kinda hopeless)

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you might want to try increasing the indent with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>  and decreasing the indent with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

These are the keyboard shortcuts for the "increase indent" and "decrease indent" toolbar buttons.

Comment: Strange that in office 2010, this does indent, but it does not change the formatting of the bullet.  From level 1 to level 2 it's still a black bullet, not the hollowed out white one.

Answer (score -1):

I was face this problem, and finally found the solution as follows:-

1. Go to **Home** ribbon.
2. In **Paragraph** group, click dialog box launcher.

[image: Paragraph dialog box launcher]

3. In **Paragraph** dialog, go to **Indents and Spacing** tab, then click **Tabs** button.

[image: Tabs]
<sub>(source: [briarcliff.edu](https://old.briarcliff.edu/departments/cis/Word/2010/Tabs_files/image026.png))</sub>

4. Adjust **Default tab stops** value to any value greater than **0 cm** (default is **0.5 cm**).

[image: Default tab stops]

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP's question. The OP was talking about using the TAB key with a bulleted list.