# Tab key does not indent in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am having the same problem as this question here: [Tab key in Microsoft Word does not increase indent in bullet lists](https://superuser.com/q/144909/66419). But the answer provided doesn't seem to work in Powerpoint 2010 anymore. This is the option list that I found, but I can't find the option needed:

[image: AutoCorrect options list]

Answer (score 3):

PowerPoint behaves the way you'd expect it to re bullets and tabs when you're entering text into a body text placeholder, but not when you're entering text into a regular text shape or other shape.

If it's not a text placeholder, use the Increase List Level and Decrease List Level buttons on the Paragraph group of the Home tab instead of using the tab key.

Comment: Also wont work.

Answer (score -1):

I found that when I use themes, sometimes I experience this and other strange behavior with bulleted lists. What I do when I encounter this problem is just delete the text box and then insert a new one. It works every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying? What is "this"? what is the strange behavior, what text box are you deleting, what themes are you speaking of?