# Microsoft Word 2010 - Tab does not increase bullet indents

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm looking at the solution here: [Microsoft Word - When I hit tab, it no longer indents the bullet-point in a list](https://superuser.com/questions/387262/microsoft-word-when-i-hit-tab-it-no-longer-indents-the-bullet-point-in-a-list).

However I already have that auto format option checked. Turning it off/on again and restarting MS Word does not fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Some file or someone working on you box might have changed the default styles.

Close Word. Go to folder location where Normal.dotm (or if Normal.dot is applicable for 2013) is stored on HDD. rename that file to anything.

Start word, it will recreate a fresh Normal.dot(m) with default settings. Check whether the problem is gone. If not, undo the above, close word, delete new normal.dot(m), rename your changed name to normal.dot(m) if it is having many of your settings.