# Pressing Tab deletes all text after cursor in a bulleted list - MS Word in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I cannot tab anymore the text inside lists.  Every time I press the tab on my keyboard to insert the tab character, instead of doing so, it deletes all the text on the same line I wish to insert Tab.  Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Make sure **Insert** is not on.

Comment: @Molx - I have Word 2010, and I can't replicate the issue erotavlas is having, whether Insert is on or off.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck, I honestly suggested without testing because Insert is a common source of this behaviour, but couldn't replicate it either.

Comment: After some testing, I could partially replicate using Ctrl + Tab (which is how you would add a tab, otherwise you change the list idendation) with Insert on. But it only deletes the first character, not the entire line.

Comment: I had this problem, too, and I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/387262/microsoft-word-when-i-hit-tab-it-no-longer-indents-the-bullet-point-in-a-list).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I tracked down to a hidden style (for some reason Word switched to it when I pressed  in a bulleted list).

I fixed it by opening styles (`<ctrl><alt><shift>+s`), and deleting **hidden style**.

Not sure what exactly the root cause was, but I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options --> Proofing ---> Autocorrect options
Tick the box as shown below (set left and first indent.....)
[image: show image]