# Is there a keyboard shortcut to indent a nested bullet point in a table cell the proper way?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Open Word and insert a table (1 x 1 will work just fine).

Right-click in the table and, in the context menu, select "Bullets" and a bullet image from the bullet library.

[image]

Type *something* and press enter.

Type *something else*, but, instead of clicking enter, right-click and select "Increase Indent"

[image]

Notice *something else* moves into the proper indentation of a nested bullet:

[image]

Outside of a Word table, you would simply press tab to get this behavior, but I want a keyboard shortcut (if available) to do this inside the table.

This is what I've tried:

- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:**  Just indents the text, not the bullet
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:**  Same as Ctrl + Tab
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>:**  Indents the text and the bullet but does not change the
  bullet style

Can this be done outside the right-click context menu?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In at least Word 2010, you can increase/decrease the indent in a bulleted or numbered list using the following keyboard shortcuts:

Windows:<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>

Mac:    <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: When combined with @user222101's comment, this is a perfect solution.  Enter twice to go up/left a level, and Shift + Alt + -> to go down/right a level.

Comment: On Mac, this is [Shift] + [Ctrl] + arrow.

Comment: Works great on Word 2013 (Windows)

Comment: Work great on Word 2016 too! You make my day!

Comment: TY SO MUCH. Been bugging me for so long. I thought Shfit+ctrl+M was the only method for a very long time.

Answer (score 11):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. It works. The first one creates the next nested line at the current indent, but the second stroke decreases the indent to the previous indent and section heading.

Comment: this only works one-way, but is still a good tip. +1

Comment: Shift+Tab also works, as well as Control+Shift+Left/Right Arrow [Mac]

Comment: @user222101, for me, Shift + Tab moves me to the left one table cell and selects the content of the cell.

Comment: This i a very simple (and effective) solution to move up one level when on the second level (or deeper) in a bulleted list, inside a table.  It even remembers where you have the margins set for each level, if you customized them (which I always do when bulleting inside a table, to avoid extraneous leading whitespace).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For mac word 2011 also see,

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to decrease indentation of bullet
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to increase indentation of bullet

Comment: In Word for Windows, this does not change the style of the bullet to the default for that indent level. See the other answers if you want that.

Comment: These worked for me in Microsoft Word for Mac (version 16.6)

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro (using the Developer tab), and assign it to a keyboard shortcut combination. 
(Using the Macro Recorder is the easiest way to set this up, but you could also just insert the command `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent` in the macro VBA.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>right arrow</kbd>/<kbd>left arrow</kbd> works for me inside a table!

Comment: worked inside table for word 2016

Answer (score 1):

For **Word 2011 for Mac** the combination that works is:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You might also try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.  It's bound to function `IncreaseIndent` in Word 2010.

Comment: did you try this before you suggested it?

Comment: Absolutely.  And it works for me.

Comment: UPDATE: The `Alt+RightArrow` works for me in a table, but `TAB` doesn't.  Thought I had tried it in a table before.  I've editted my answer accordingly.

Comment: neither method works for me (also running Word 2010 on Win7).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for increasing indent and decreasing indent shortcuts for Microsoft Word 2019. Look below,

Increase Indent: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
Decrease Indent: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

option + command + arrow left/right

Comment: While not stated, the context of the question makes it clear this question is about Windows, while your answer is about Apple.

Answer (score -1):

Increase indent.. TAB
Decrease indent.. SHIFT + TAB

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(an answer has been accepted) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: Did you notice that the question says ‘‘in a table cell’’?  Have you tried this in a table cell?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to solve the issue was creating a new keyboard shortcut for the IncreaseIndent and DecreaseIndent.

Go to `File` > `Options` > `Customize Ribbon` > `Keyboard Shortcuts "Customize"`. From there, Look under `Categories: All Commands` > `IncreaseIndent`. Lastly, under `Press new shortcut key:` (add your command).

I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for `DecreaseIndent`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> for `IncreaseIndent`.

These commands are unused, and are in relative correlation with the keyboard shortcut used for increase indent outside of a text box - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

shift + tab is the shortcut to decrease the bullet point level

Comment: Nope, doesn't work inside a table, which is the context in which the question is being asked.