# Microsoft Word: Shortcut to add a sub bullet (Inside a table)

Tags: microsoft-word, hotkeys, bullets

The way to add a sub bullet in Word with hotkey is hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. But I can't do that if bullets are inside a table.

[image: Screenshot of Word menu]

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Tab?

Comment: Ctrl+Tab indents, but doesn't change the bullet list level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>

(From https://superuser.com/a/511543/368970)